# SwiftUI - ObservableObject created multiple times

Tags: navigationview, swiftui, observableobject

I have created an ObservableObject in a View.

```
@ObservedObject var selectionModel = FilterSelectionModel()
```

I put a breakpoint inside the `FilterSelectionModel`'s `init` function and it is called multiple times. Because this View is part of a `NavigationLink`, I understand that it gets created then and along with it, the selectionModel. When I navigate to the View, the selectionModel is created again.

In this same View I have a "sub View" where I pass the selectionModel as an `EnvironmentObject` so the sub-view can change it.

```
AddFilterScreen().environmentObject(self.selectionModel)
```

When the sub view is dismissed, the selectionModel is once more created and the changes made to it have disappeared.

*Interesting Note*: At the very top level is a `NavigationView`. IF I add

```
.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
```

to this `NavigationView`, my selectionModel's changes disappear. BUT if I **do not** add the `navigationStyle`, the selectionModel's changes made in the sub view remain!! (But I don't want a split nav view, I want a stacked nav view)

In both cases - with or without the `navigationStyle`, the selectionModel is created multiple times. I can't wrap my head around how any of this is supposed to work reliably.

Comment: *UPDATE*: I "solved" this problem by breaking encapsulation and moving the `FilterSelectionModel` to the top `ContentView`. But I don't like this solution since this model is needed only by the set of views involved in my app's search functions. The entire app does not need to know about this model.

Comment: I have been struggling with the same problem. Do not know how to solve this in an elegant way without breaking encapsulation as you say.

Comment: Any new update? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: No updates as of right now.

Comment: Same issue. I ended up using a singleton for my view model as a workaround... 

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Latest SwiftUI updates have brought solution to this problem. (iOS 14 onwards)

`@StateObject` is what we should use instead of `@ObservedObject`, but only where that object is created and not everywhere in the sub-views where we are passing the same object.

For eg-

```
class User: ObservableObject {
    var name = "mohit"
}


struct ContentView: View {
  @StateObject var user = User()

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("name: \(user.name)")
      NameCount(user: self.user)
   }
  }
}


struct NameCount: View {
  @ObservedObject var user

  var body: some View {
    Text("count: \(user.name.count)")
  }
}
```

In the above example, only the view responsible (*ContentView*) for creating that object is annotating the `User` object with `@StateObject` and all other views (*NameCount*) that share the object is using `@ObservedObject`.

By this approach whenever your parent view(*ContentView*) is re-created, the `User` object will not be re-created and it will persist its *@State*, while your child views just `observing` to the same `User` object doesn't have to care about its re-creation.

Answer (score 9):

You can instantiate the observable object in the init method, in this way you will be able to hold its value or the value won't disappear.

Instantiate this way in the view file.

```
@ObservedObject var selectionModel : FilterSelectionModel

init() {
   selectionModel = FilterSelectionModel(value : "value to be saved from disappearing")
}
```

Instantiate this way in the viewModel file.

```
class FilterSelectionModel : ObservableObject {

  @Published var value : String

  init(value : String) {
     self.value = value
  }

}
```

This is a workaround that I found, but still, the init method is called multiple times and I didn't get any success with this issue.

In order to stop multiple initializing of the ViewModels as the view is declared in the Navigation View and SwiftUI uses struct which is a value type, so eventually these are initialized before the view is presented, therefore you can convert that view into a LazyView, so that it will only be initialized once the view is about to be presented or shown.

```
// Use this to delay instantiation when using `NavigationLink`, etc...
struct LazyView<Content: View>: View {
    var content: () -> Content
    var body: some View {
       self.content()
    }
}
```

You can call it like this...

```
 NavigationLink(destination: LazyView { ViewTobePresented() })
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The LazyView works.

Comment: Objects should only be init in the property wrapped definition, otherwise you'll be initing and destroying objects when the View structs are created on every update.

Comment: @malhal can you provide an example,  how to do it with property wrapper definition.

Comment: @AnshumanSingh the pattern Apple use (see Data Essentials in SwiftUI WWDC 2020 at 20:20) is to init the @ StateObject with no params and then call a method on the object supplying it with the params in the View's onAppear.